# Changing php.ini on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to configure my beanstalk application, setting the `max_input_vars=5000` in `php.ini`.

I found [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/470244/how-to-replace-php-ini-on-elastic-beanstalk-ec2-instances-for-php) which does pretty close to what I want except a little different. Instead of copying from S3 I just want to create a file with that line. The below is my code in a file named `phpini.config` found in the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder.

```
files:
    "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      max_input_vars=5000
```

However, the value is not changing, as I seen when I run `phpinfo()`, nor is there a `project.ini` file created in `/etc/php.d/`.

Is there something I am missing out? Or is there a way I can see if this config file is being run?

**Edit**

Seems like the `.config` file is supposed to be in `.ebextensions` instead of `.elasticbeanstalk` according to [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html). Making the change didnt make things work though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cleanest way what we did to install a svn plugin that is  to use a .ebextensions config file in my project archive:

Sample you can go like this create a file .ebextensions/eb.config file:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      u max_input_vars=5000
```

Comment: not sure exactly how different yours is from mine. but I must admit it works now. thumbs up~

Comment: Glad that works issue is only permissions mode: "000777" changes to mode: "000644"

Comment: I already had a config file making other tweaks, so all I needed was to add the: max_input_vars=5000

Answer (score 1):

I tried the abaid778 snippet code and does not work so I remove de 'u' before max_input_vars and that work now.

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      max_input_vars = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the previous suggestions work but was able to change the php.ini value with .htaccess:

> php_value max_input_vars 5000

[How to set the max_input_vars directive in an .htaccess file](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-max-input-vars-directive-in-an-htaccess-file)

Comment: I had used this until recently, but it seems AWS no longer supports it on new instances.